# Active directory migration 2008 to 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, migration

After so many hours of pulling my hair i end up here for some help.
I also want to apologize for my English since its not my native tongue.

We currently have a Windows Server 2008 which we need to migrate to a newer system due to third party software support has been cut.

The guide/checklist I followed:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/05/28/step-by-step-active-directory-migration-from-windows-server-2008-r2-to-windows-server-2012.aspx

What I found are that a active directory migration is the best to keep all running clients on the new server.
On a test between two clean virtual machines it works flawless without any errors and i can shut down the old DC once everything is complete letting the new DC handle logins etc etc.

I do the same thing as i did on the virtual machine on the real server environment everything works well until the new DC are restarted and NETLOGIN and SYSVOL isn't shared, the new DC cant handle logins.
I get errors which say once the sync between the servers have been completed SYSVOL will be shared, but it will never be completed.
So i move the FSMO roles to the new DC still SYSVOL aren't shared.
Event viewer errors after promotion:

- Event 1202, DFSR
- Event 13512, NtFrs
- Event 13565, NtFrs

After some hours of sleep I try preforming a "install from media" (**IFM**) i extract the active directory from the domain into a file I import into the new server active directory promotion, validation are successful.
After 2 min of preparing the file server restarts and leave an error in the event viewer:
Code:
NTDS (436) NTDSA: Database 'C:\Windows\NTDS\ntds.dit': The secondary index 'INDEX_00150003' of table 'datatable' may be corrupt. If there is no later event showing the index being rebuilt, then please defragment the database to rebuild the index.
Old DC and the new DC are on the same network without any firewall and there's no clients or anything on this separate network

Roles on old DC:

- AD DS
- DHCP
- DNS
- File Share

New DC are new installed with nothing else than AD DS installed for the migration.

I'm stuck, i cant get active directory migrated to the new server.
Any input are highly appreciated!

-Draax

Answer (score 0):

Did a lot of migration, and that happened a lot to have a missing sysvol/netlogon. When by example the folder is using FRS, not DFS to sync, as the new folder never sync up.

See

How to rebuild the SYSVOL tree and its content in a domain : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315457

Using the BurFlags registry key to reinitialize File Replication Service replica sets  | https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290762

In my case I ended up dooing the burflags AND some time I had to manually copy the folder and start both share to have the replication start.